# While loop in OR condition not working. BASH shell

Tags: bash, shell, input, while-loop, boolean

I am trying to run a shell script in OS X Terminal. The program terminates whenever you enter an m or a.

Problem is, I can't get the OR statement working.

```
#!/bin/sh
read File

while [ "$File" != "m" ] || [ "$File" != "a" ]
do
read File
done
```

When I just do

```
while [ "$File" != "m" ]
```

It works perfectly fine. I have tried multiple methods, such as

```
while test $File != "m" || test $File != "a"
while test $File != "m" -o test $File != "a"
while [ $File != "m" -o $File != "a" ]
```

None of them seem to work. 
The above code I posted does not stop looping when the user inputs an "m" or an

Comment: Probably you want `&&` instead of `||`.  The condition you are using now will always evaluate to true, because if either of the alternatives evaluates false, the other one certainly evaluates true.  In other words, your logic is dubious.

Comment: This construct is also very strange.  It would be much cleaner to write it as `while read File; do if test "$File" = m || "$file" = a; then break; fi ...` .  Your current construction does not check if any `read` fails, so it will behave strangely when the input stream terminates.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to replace

```
while [ "$File" != "m" ] || [ "$File" != "a" ]
```

by

```
while [ "$File" != "m" ] && [ "$File" != "a" ]
```

or

```
until [ "$File" = "m" ] || [ "$File" = "a" ]
```

or with a regex (bash):

```
while [[ ! $File =~ m|a ]]
```

See from bash: `help until`